# Unreal Engine Assertion Failure EdNodeGraph Line 599

Tags: crash, unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint

whenever I try to open my unreal project I get the following error/crash.

`Assertion failed: Result [File:D:\UnrealEngineStuff\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\EdGraph\EdGraphNode.h] [Line: 599]`

I see that this is checking for a pin in the correct direction but really don't know how to fix it or what caused it in the first place. I can't open any of my blueprints as opening any of them causes the project to crash again.

Any ideas?